# Google Calendars: method of keeping track of API refresh tokens

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am using Google Calendar API to have offline access to user calendars.

So when a user first authenticates the app, I am given a refresh token.

On subsequent accesses, no refresh token is given.

So in order to keep these, I am storing the refresh token against my own database user table. So I know when a particular user of the site is logged in, that the Google refresh token is $refresh

This works just fine when the user only uses 1 Google account, but if they authenticate the app across multiple Google accounts. There are multiple refresh tokens, but on my database side, I am storing just one.

So the first thing to do was to store all refresh tokens, tying them all to the single website user.

But even still this is incorrect, When granting access to a specific calendar, I won't know what Google account that particular calendar is associated with. (unless I am missing something)

So when they grant access to a calendar, all I have to go with, is what user was signed into my website.

So if someone grants access to say 2 calendars, which are in 2 different Google accounts, but both tied to the one website user. How can I know which Google account was used for which calendar?

Without knowing that info, the refresh token is going to fail until I pick the right refresh token. Which would have to be done by cycling though the refresh tokens until one works.

Is there some way to store something that would help me know which refresh token is tied to each calendar (rather than only tying it to a website user) they have authenticated?

Or is my methodology wrong in the way I am storing the data, and there is a better way to store this info that makes better sense.

Answer (score 0):

A refresh token is obtained in offline scenarios during the first authorization code exchange. Even though user has multiple accounts, refresh token is generated for each google account(even users are same).
Also, when you are storing the refresh token in your database store refresh token along with the user ID(google account id) and calendar ID(even though both ID's are same but in few scenarios, each user can have multiple calendars).